# scheme full padding example using format

Tags: scheme, racket

all

I want to change a element to formatted string, then I use format function. (the language I use is scheme )

As the document in http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Format.html said, I can use  ~mincolA if I want inserts spaces on the right.

So I use

```
(format "~4A " x)
```

but I get an error like that:

```
format: ill-formed pattern string
  explanation: tag `~4' not allowed
  pattern string: "~4A "
```

I want to get the result like below:

> if x is 0, then the result is space space space 0;
>
> if x is 12, then the result is space space 12.

I know I can use

```
(string-append (make-string (- 4 (string-length x)) #\ ) x)
```

to get the result I want, but I really want use "format" function.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there no answer you'd consider acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the referenced documentation is for MIT/GNU Scheme, the [`format`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._format%29%29) function works different in Racket. Out-of-the-box, you can use the [`~a`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7ea%29%29) function for the same effect:

```
(~a x #:min-width 4 #:align 'right #:left-pad-string " ") ; x can be a number or a string
```

For example:

```
(~a 0 #:min-width 4 #:align 'right #:left-pad-string " ")
=> "   0"

(~a "12" #:min-width 4 #:align 'right #:left-pad-string " ")
=> "  12"
```

If you don't mind importing an additional external library, @uselpa's answer is spot-on.

Comment: I would call it neither an additional nor an external library, since it is included in the Racket installation. It's just not required by default with `#lang racket`.

Comment: Well, it's not there out-of-the box, that's what I mean. I'm not a big fan of importing another library just for some functionality that's already in the core language, albeit with a different syntax. It's a kind of code duplication, not to mention an additional dependency and memory overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `format` procedure from [SRFI 48](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-48.html):

```
> (require srfi/48)
> (format "~4F" 0)
"   0"
> (format "~4F" 12)
"  12"
```

If you want to keep the original `format` procedure along with this one, you can give the one from SRFI 48 a prefix:

```
> (require (prefix-in srfi48: srfi/48))
> (srfi48:format "~4F" 0)
```

so the original `format` is still available.

Answer (score 1):

Scheme doesn't have a `format` procedure, but one is available in [SRFI-48](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-48.html). It is not compatible with either MIT Scheme nor #!racket (the language).

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (srfi :48))

(format "~4F " "x") ; ==> "   x"
```

You can use SRFI-48 with #!racket in similar manner:

```
#!racket
(require srfi/48)

(format "~4F " "x") ; ==> "   x"
```

`F` works only for numbers and strings according to the documentation:

> ~[w[,d]]F     Fixed   ~w,dF outputs a number with width w and d digits
>   after the decimal; ~wF outputs a string or number with width w.

Also by evaluating `(format "~h")` you get instructions for use so for the basic reminder on syntax you don't need to visit the SRFI page.

Comment: Wish one could tag answers. `r6rs` would do it for this :)